# Cypress carry state from one Iteration Block to other Iteration Block

Tags: javascript, automation, scripting, cypress

I am working with cypress and can't find a way to carry my current state to another iteration within a spec file and i have multiple specs file.

for Eg:

I opened a staff list, and i clicked on add staff button. A pop up form open and I just created a staff and form closes with success toaster and I am back on the staff list. The iteration script ends with it and in my next iteration I want to search that staff which i created but the issue I face is that I had to give him cy.visit() command to take me back to that staff list.

I am unable to find a solution and kind of stuck

Answer (score 2):

The package [cypress-data-session](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-data-session) looks like a good fit.

It allows you to be explicit about the data that is carried from one test to another, at the same time preserves integrity of test isolation.

Example:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  // let's say you want to set up the value "A"
  cy.dataSession(
    'A', // data name
    () => 'a', // data creation commands
    (x) => x === 'a', // data validation function
  )
})

it('has object A', () => {
  expect(Cypress.getDataSession('A')).to.equal('a')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Having tests that are not independent of other tests is not considered a best practice in Cypress (and I'd argue, almost any other testing tool.) [This Cypress blog post](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2023/03/08/test-isolation-as-a-best-practice) gives some good reasons why it is a best practice, as well as the [Cypress core-concept documentation.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-isolation)

Instead, I'd suggest creating a function that can create the staff member *without* the use of the UI.

```js
// This is just a pseudo example
describe('My tests', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('/foo');
  });

  it('validates users can create staff members', () => {
    // code to validate user can create staff members via UI
  });

  it('validates created staff members appear on the webpage', () => {
    cy.createStaffMember(); // custom helper function you've written to create the staff member 
    // the ideal scenario would be that the above helper function does not use the UI
    
    // remaining portion of the test that validates staff member appears on the webpage 
  });
});
```

*Why should the second test create it's own test data?* There are a few reasons, but the most compelling for me is that Test 2 will fail if Test 1 fails. If Test 1 fails to create the data, then obviously, Test 2 will fail. You'll have cascading failures for any tests that have these dependencies on a test, and the singular reason why won't always be obvious. If Tests 1 and 2 are independent, you'll have an easier time debugging failures.

*However*, if, for whatever reason, it is not feasible/reasonable/possible to have Tests 1 and 2 be isolated from one another, you can disable Test Isolation. An alternative would be to combine Tests 1 and 2 into a singular test (which, while less atomic than the alternative, still seems to be a better solution than disabling Test Isolation.)

Comment: Hi thankyou for your swift reply. 
The Issue i face is when i move to next iteration i have to give command of visiting the URL which i want to avoid, whether i Interact with UI or create custom commands

Comment: Ah - you can you `beforeEach()` to repeat functionality _before_ each `it()` block runs. https://filiphric.com/cypress-basics-before-beforeeach-after-aftereach

Comment: I m already using it, I m calling my Custom Login command in beforeach() and maintaining the session with in that command.  Now the issue that i face is In every Iteration block  I have to hard code the Cy.visit() in every iteration and when one iteration completes it blanks all the data and take us to about blank page and it reloads the all url() in the next iteration which often fails the test as Cypress is Asynchronous. I had to make him wait using cy.wait()